# jQuery on() docs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

Are the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for jQuery's `on()` function incorrect (or unclear)?  Consider this code:

```
<div>
    <span>
        <div>
            <input type="button" value="click me!" />
        </div>
    </span>
</div>

$(document).on("click", function() {
    console.log(this.toString());
});
```

The docs state

> **selector** A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected
>   elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted,
>   the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

Clicking the button only causes one console.log for the document itself, while `$(document).on("click", "*", function()...` causes many.

I know the Stack Overflow community isn't responsible for the jQuery docs, but shouldn't they say that when the selector is omitted, the event is **only** triggered when it reaches the selected element?  Or is there something about event delegation I'm not understanding correctly?

[Complete fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fw8Zv/)

Comment: Would you expect `$('#mydiv').on('click',function(){ });` tot rigger when `#myotherdiv` is clicked? The premise is the same, it will work based on how vague/specific your parameters are.

Comment: The word "reaches" seems to imply the word "only".

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding, as the documentation seems pretty clear to me.  If you add a click event handler to $(document) then it is just the document that has the event handler attached.  If you add it to every element in the document, as described in the documentation, it will be attached to the document and all child elements, which is exactly what it does.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @mblase75 - I think yours is the best answer so far - can you make it an answer ?

Comment: It also means that an event where `isPropagationStopped()` may not have reached the element that's listening for the event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no event delegation when you leave the selector out. From the docs:

> If selector is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as
>   direct or directly-bound. The handler is called every time an event
>   occurs on the selected elements, whether it occurs directly on the
>   element or bubbles from a descendant (inner) element.
>
> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as
>   delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on
>   the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that
>   match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up
>   to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to
>   outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that
>   path matching the selector.

Basically `.on` is doing the jQuery thing --  it is overloaded to do completely different things depending on arguments. Personally I prefer `.delegate` for delegation, and `.bind` for normal events, as they are much clearer and I hope they don't get removed in later versions.

Comment: *grin* thank you - bad developer, read the docs more patiently, smack, bad developer...

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think it's clear enough. When the selector is omitted the event is triggered when it reaches the selected element. The word "always" doesn't really change the meaning in my opinion. The event *will* always be triggered when it reaches the selected element (note that if something like `stopPropagation` is called, the event will not reach the selected element and therefore won't be triggered).

When a selector is present, the event is triggered when it reaches the selected element having originated from an element matching the selector.

When you use the universal selector `*` every single element between the event target and the selected element will trigger the event.

As you stated in your comment, `on` provides all the functionality you need to bind events in jQuery 1.7+:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers.

Comment: So it seems like leaving out the selector can make `on` an exact replacement for `bind`?  `$("X").bind("click", function` === `$("X").on("click", function` ??

Comment: Indeed it is. That's the whole point of `on`, it encompasses all the different ways you could bind events previously into one (`bind`, `delegate` and `live` are no longer necessary).

Comment: +1 - thanks for your answer.  I guess the root of the problem was that I didn't read the docs fully enough, as Ensalija showed me.  Hopefully I'm not the only dev in the world that has this problem...